# Do we need a canonical for Python ModuleNotFoundErrors?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, canonical

Lately I've noticed that we've got a lot of [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) questions about `ModuleNotFoundError`s. As in, [3330 questions a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+ModuleNotFoundError+is%3Aq).

Most of these questions seem to have the root cause of the module not being installed or being installed incorrectly. Just a couple random examples:

- [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.framework'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489262/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tensorflow-contrib-framework)
- [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48972115/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-crypto)
- [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552036/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-psycopg2)
- [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mdptoolbox'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54400430/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-mdptoolbox)

I would suggest that we decide on one of these questions (or create a new one) and close all the `ModuleNotFoundError` questions with the same root cause as a duplicate of the question we decide on.

Thoughts? Discussion? Waffles?

Comment: Yes, the problem is caused by the module not being found, that's clear. The issue with closing as a duplicate is that the users are expecting the module to be found, and are confused as to why it isn't. This will usually boil down to the user importing the wrong thing, and the specific mistake is going to differ. A canonical for this would be so useless it would border on nonsense. Closing the questions as duplicates of the canonical without any other explanation would be so absolutely frustrating with no positive outcome for anyone involved. How would this make the internet a better place?

Comment: @TinyGiant it would make the internet a better place by keeping all answers in one place so they can be more easily updated, and by directing users to an exhaustive answer that probably outlines why they are getting the error. Whereas currently, the majority of these questions are unanswered with a few relatively unhelpful comments.

Comment: But an answer that is general enough to apply to all situations would only say "You're receiving this error because the module was not found", and that would be completely useless and not worth the bits that it would be comprised of. Otherwise the specific answer is going to be different for every question, making the questions not duplicates.

Comment: @TinyGiant no, an answer general enough to apply to all situations would say "You're receiving this error because the module was not found. Depending on the situation, you can fix it by ..." My whole point is that the answer will *not* be different for every question, because most of them are caused by the same thing. The ones causes by something different can be left open.

Comment: So you want one answer that would attempt to answer every possible question regarding a module not being found? I think that would be equally useless. Now I get my question closed as a duplicate of a massive wall of stuff that it might possibly be, but there's also a chance that my issue is not included and now I'm for sure to not receive an answer, and everyone who happens to have that same issue will be directed to an answer that doesn't include the solution to their problem. We don't need one answer that contains solutions to every problem ever.

Comment: We need a canonical for the "how to find the canonical" meta question.  "Try the chat room" is the usual answer.

Comment: @TinyGiant I think you're misunderstanding my proposal. I'm not proposing that we make one question related to every possible case of a `ModuleNotFoundError`. I'm proposing that we make one canonical for `ModuleNotFoundError`s caused by a module not being installed or being installed correctly. A canonical answer for this wouldn't really be that long.

Comment: All I can see coming from it is a lot of frustrated people not finding the solution to their problems.

Comment: @TinyGiant I see people quickly finding solutions to their problems through the marking-as-duplicate process.

Comment: Except that isn't how it is used in situations like this. How it works is "Oh, I see ModuleNotFoundError -> don't read anything else -> hammer as duplicate -> walk away and never return".

Comment: @TinyGiant simple solution: make it clear in the canonical's title that it only provides a solution when the problem is because the module isn't installed correctly.

Comment: Which will change precisely nothing.

Comment: @TinyGiant it will solve the problem you just mentioned. It will be clearer that it is not a canonical for *all* ModuleNotFoundError problems, and users will read through it more carefully before closing.

Comment: canonicals are good. common easily researched questions are bad. a canonical we can close these easily researched questions with that teaches the user how to debug/resolve the very common beginner issue with is a win-win solution.

Comment: @Pikachu It won't change anything because the people closing won't care to determine whether or not the question is caused by the user just not installing the module. They'll just want to close that "common easily researched question" that they identified by reading a single word or phrase while completely ignoring the rest of the question.

Comment: Fortunately, dupe closure can be reversed, and if someone is abusing it, that can be reported. the fact that it will eventually be abused isn't a reason to not have it.

Comment: @TinyGiant people abuse the reviewing system. Should we remove it because it's not always used well? No, it's still very useful to have. This is the same thing. Yes, it might be abused by gold tag badge holders, but, as Kevin mentioned, it's easy to find and easy to reverse.

Comment: No, but I don't think we should make the problem worse. There isn't an issue right now, and your suggestion would create one that doesn't currently exist. The fact that questions can be reopened has been used to hand-wave every existing problem with the closure system for years, that hasn't stopped _anyone_ from blatantly abusing the closure system.

Comment: @TinyGiant so, having a ton of questions asking the same thing and having the same root cause that aren't closed as a duplicate isn't an issue?

Comment: They don't have the same root cause, they have the same error, all with different root causes.

Comment: @TinyGiant no, lots of them have the same cause: a module not being installed or being installed correctly. I'm not proposing a canonical for other ModuleNotFoundError questions.

Comment: And what will happen is that all future questions will get closed as a duplicate of your supposed canonical regardless of whether or not that applies. Hence the problem you're creating that didn't already exist.

Comment: @TinyGiant we've already been through this: yes, there will be people who abuse the system. But that doesn't mean it's a bad system. This form of abuse is especially easy to dig up and also very easy to revert.

Comment: Sure, and every abuse of the closure system since inception is easy to dig up and revert, but that largely does not happen, and there isn't a problem with these questions as they are right now, but there will be with your suggested solution.

Comment: @TinyGiant there is a problem: there are lots of questions with the same error and same root cause, and we don't have a clear question to close them as a duplicate of. Creating a canonical would solve that problem.

Comment: Waffles? Is that a new meme? Or the [old one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19480#19480)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen the old one you linked to. New waffles aren't *quite* as good...

Comment: @TinyGiant Such a canonical dupe target works quite well for [C++ "undefined reference" linker errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/1782465). Or for [errors about missing `typename` or `template` keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/1782465).

Comment: @Angew Yeah, just like the NullPointerException canonical is used as a duplicate target for every single question that even mentions an NPE regardless of whether or not the canonical is even remotely relevant to the question asked or the problem being asked about. It's just an easy way for someone to say "I don't want to answer questions on this topic anymore so I'm going to close every question on this topic as a duplicate of some massive wall of text that may or may not be tangentially relevant. My time is much more important than everyone else's time, and I couldn't possibly just _move on_"

Comment: @Angew Those work typically horribly wrong. I see it every time when a question has both the fortran and the c++ tag. C++ guys see undefined reference -> immediate closure. See the edit history [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55360745/revisions), it needed a fortranner to be re-opened. Also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381483/very-broad-duplicate-targets

Comment: Many questions are really due to OP not even trying to install the module... I tend to think that we can and should close these questions as "not reproducible". Most of the remaining questions are about using the wrong interpreter for installation, i.e. the wrong version of pip, for which [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip) is not a bad canonical. What else would such a hypothetical canonical add?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56514189/python-modulenotfounderror/56514190#56514190

Comment: https://smartmanoj.blogspot.com/2019/06/python-modulenotfounderror.html

Comment: @Pikachuthe, "A canonical answer for this wouldn't really be that long". You'd be surprised ;-)  There apparently are quite a number of reasons why users can get this error. But I don't think a long answer is always bad. A well-structured answer that explains the basics and covers most scenarios would certainly be useful, IMHO.

Comment: About the whole "closing as duplicate" discussion: I think that if a *short* "ModuleNotFoundError" question is asked, we can point to the canonical answer then. And if that does not solve the problem, then the new question can be edited to include additional information which makes it a unique question, right? I'm not completely familiar with the opening/closing process for duplicates yet, but this is my current understanding of it. Correct me if I'm wrong. If a user has provided enough details so we know that it's a *different* problem/question, then of course we should not close it as dup.

Comment: @wovano my proposal is that we only close as a duplicate when it's clear that the canonical solves the problem. If it doesn't cover the OP's specific situation, then it should be left open. If it gets closed as dup but still doesn't solve the problem, there is a process to reopen it after it gets edited or receives a reopen vote.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed the same! And I've found that there are several, similar but subtly different causes for this problems. In the most basic case, a user just forgot to install a package using `pip install <package>`. However, in many other cases the user *did* execute command, but in another Python environment, so that they still got the `ModuleNotFoundError` when executing their code. Sometimes it depends on *how* they execute the code.

I've written quite a comprehensive [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56451612/10669875) for one of these [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56449253/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyaudio-windows)s, trying to explain everything needed to know to understand why this happens and how to solve it. Since then I try to direct persons with the same question to that answer in the hope that this answer would solve this problem "once and for all" ;-) Otherwise the same "interview" (did you try this? did you try that? how did you install it? how did you run it? etc.) has to be repeated everytime...

My answer focuses on Windows, but some of it is true for other operating systems as well. I still want to extend my answer with some info about virtual environments, but I think it is a useful answer already. Suggestions/improvements are welcome of course. Please leave a comment and I'll try to improve it if necessary.

What do you think? Could this be a canonical answer for (many, probably not all) `ModuleNotFoundError`-questions?